# Julia DataFrame: shift a column by more rows

Tags: dataframe, julia, shift

I am looking for a way how to shift DataFrame column by more rows.

Shifting by one row works fine:

```
df = DataFrame(A=[1,2,3,4], B=[9,8,7,6])

julia> transform(df, "A" => ShiftedArrays.lag => :A1)
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B      A1
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64?
─────┼───────────────────────
   1 │     1      9  missing
   2 │     2      8        1
   3 │     3      7        2
   4 │     4      6        3
```

But I am not able to find out how to transform the entire column with a function with more arguments, something like this (neither works):

```
transform(df, "A" => x -> ShiftedArrays.lag(x, 2) => :A1)
```

or

```
transform(df, ["A", 2] => f => :A1)
```

I hope there is a more suitable solution than using of for loop :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need additional parentheses around the anonymous function:

```py
transform(df, "A" => (x -> ShiftedArrays.lag(x, 2)) => :A1)

Result:
 Row │ A      B      A1      
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64?  
─────┼───────────────────────
   1 │     1      9  missing 
   2 │     2      8  missing 
   3 │     3      7        1
   4 │     4      6        2
```

Comment: It's not a “lambda” function. Please don't use terms that belong to other languages. In Julia, we call those functions **"anonymous functions"**.

Comment: @Shayan Lambda calculus is almost a century old, and the term "lambda" for anonymous functions comes from that field. It's a useful term to know in general, it doesn't *belong* to any particular programming language.

Comment: @Shayan I changed the wording to the one you've suggested.